# Mvc View: best use of it with model class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My question is what do I have to do and to do not to show data in a view?

For example I have in my view this model class

> `@model IEnumerable<MyProg.Models.MyObj>`

which are the best and worst way to handle these data (MyObj)???

can declare a variable?
can assign value a variable?
can fetch data with foreach?

is rigth to do all of it or is possible only to fetch data passed from controller?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a vague question, but if you're looking for some pointers... The easiest way would be to leave the model declaration as-is, and use foreach to iterate over the results in your View:

```
foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @item.MyProperty etc...
}
```

You could create a model that includes a MyObj collection property because you may want to pass more than just the collection to the view:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public IEnumerable<MyProg.Models.MyObj> MyCollection{get; set;}
   public string AnotherProperty{get; set;}
}
```

So your view would look like this:

```
@model Models.MyModel

foreach(var item in Model.MyCollection)
{
   ...
}
```